# Creating Different Permutations from different Arrays Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to write a method which allows me to create a different String permutations, based on the values I have stored within 3 different arrays. Currently I have a `NSMutableDictionary` that contains 3 different keys, and associated to each key we have an `NSMutableArray` array that contains a list of different String objects.

How woulld I loop through each of my `NSMutableArray` arrays which are stored within my `NSMutableDictionary`, and build a string value for each node from the arrays. So essentially, something like the following: `A1[0] = "Hello"`, `A2[0] = "There"`, `A3[0] = "Guys"`, which would essentially build me a string like this: "HelloThereGuys".

Any suggestions, or possibly different approaches to this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to agree with hochl. ;-) But I think, that you want to create a string containing a word from each array in the same index position?

```
NSMutableArray *enums = [NSMutableArray new];
for( NSString *key in dictionary )
{ 
  NSEnumerator *enum = [dictionary[key] objectEnumerator]; // Forgot that in prior version
  [enums addObject:enum];
}

while( YES )
{
  NSMutableString *line = [NSMutableString new];
  BOOL done = NO;
  for( NSEnumerator *enum in enums ) 
  {
    NString *word = [enum nextObject];
    if( word == nil )
    {
      done = YES;
      break;
    }

    [line addString:word];
  }

  if (done)
  {
    break;
  }

  NSLog (@"%@", line );
}
```

Did I get you right?

Comment: Amin spot on. That is exactly what I am wanting to do. There are 3 `NSEnumerator` class objects explicitly defined in your example, what if we have more than 3 keys in the dictionary?

Comment: You can iterate through the keys creating an instance of `NSEnumerator` for each and store this instances into an array. … Ah, wait, I will add that …

Comment: Amin, could you please add that to you answer?

Comment: Did it. Still typped in Safari.

Comment: Amin, is there a way where I could get all the different combinations with this method, or is that a different approach? So, for example, create a string which contains the first word from the first array move onto the second array and get the first word, and the finally move onto the last array and get all the possible outcomes. Then move onto the next word within the first array, and so on...

Comment: In this case you have to nest the iterations. To do that with an unknown number of keys, means that you have to do that recursively.